# Laradock - Localhost not working on Windows 7 using Nginx

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, windows-7, laradock

I have setup a laradock app on my local machine. I have followed the instructions as provided: http://laradock.io/

In addition to that as I am on Windows 7, and using Docker toolbox

when access to localhost I get this error This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

in the condition you are using toolbox, you must place your project and laradock to `c:\users\your-user`, or make symlink to this forder. Check your docker machine ip using `docker-machine ip default` . Then access your-docker-ip and you will see your laravel app.